# Can't get a string array to copy one random value

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
void getName(char* value)
{

  const char *nameArray[] = { "bob", "billy", "jimbob", "boba fett", "chuck norris", "jimmy", "craig",
        "howard", "leonard", "raj", "sheldon", "penny", "jenny", "sean", "amy", "bernadette",
        "matthew", "olga", "ryan", "suanne", "darth vader", "luke", "spock", "kirk", "picard",
        "michele", "randy", "suanne", "bruce lee", "garrett", "sophie", "gloria"};

  int i = rand() % 33 + 1;

  strcpy(value, nameArray[i]);
  //value = nameArray[i];
}
```

I am trying to get a random name from this array and store it in value. I have debugged it and found that at `strcpy`, it crashes my program. If `strcpy` was commented out and `value = nameArray[i];` wasn't, then it wont do anything and leave the value empty. Please help!

Comment: What does the method that calls getName look like?

Comment: Q: Can you show us where you've allocated space for "value".  Hopefully, it'll look something like `char value[80];` ;)

Comment: Don't forget to initialize random seed. You can use `srand(time(NULL))` for example(you need to include time.h).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only 32 strings in the array `nameArray`. But when you do:

```
int i = rand() % 33 + 1;
```

`i` can go upto 33. So when `i` is 33, you are invoking *undefined behaviour*.

You probably want:

```
int i = rand() % 32;
```

In C, remember array indexes vary from `0` to `N-1`. NOT from 1 to N.

Also make sure you have allocated memory for `value` before copying into it.

Comment: i assume you mean `% 32` as there are only 32

Comment: @eds Thanks. Fixed it. I really didn't mean `% 32`. I simply didn't notice :)